# How to launch firefox from C program/daemon under Linux

Tags: linux, bash, firefox

I am having some problems with launching firefox from a Linux daemon written in C.
When I launch firefox on the machine itself (via terminal) from the command shell using `/usr/bin/firefox` it works OK and a firefox browser window lanunches as it should.

However if I try this within my C daemon using `system("/usr/bin/firefox")`, firefox launches its process in the terminal but the browser window is not opened?

A similar thing happens when I try to do this using remote terminal acces. It's something to do with telling the system to open firefox in window mode rather than trying to open it in terminal mode - but I dont know how to specify this using bash commands?

I am using Lubuntu 11.10 in my Linux System.
Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to launch FireFox as a daemon process? Firefox needs a terminal to operate, and daemons aren't connected to a terminal process. Do you want to download URLs in the background? You should look at [Curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html) or [Wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html).

Comment: @David: I don't think `firefox` needs a terminal. I launch my `firefox` using `dmenu` and `ps ux` output shows `firefox` does not have a controlling terminal. Seems to work alright.

Answer (score 2):

There's a reason I asked why you're attempting to do what you want. I didn't want to get into great details in my comment.

Firefox on Unix is an X-Window process (most of the Linux/Unix desktops are based upon the X11 protocol which is the heart of X-Window). What X-Window does is separate the display of the program from the process running the program. For example, I am now running Firefox from a Linux box at work, but the Linux box is actually displaying the Firefox browser window at home on my Mac.

In order to do this, I had to:

- Run X11 on my Mac. The X11 program creates a default X11 client display called `0.0` which pretty much says the first screen and the first instance of X11 running (computer geeks like counting from zero). The process runs in the background on my Mac. In a certain sense, it's really a *server* process and not a client because it's waiting on port 6000 for a *client* X11 process (Firefox) to tell it what to do.
- Before I run firefox, I have to tell my Mac's X11 process that I grant the X11 server running Firefox to be able to display on my X11 client process. Otherwise, you can imagine someone spamming another person by continuously popping up Windows on their display. You can use the `xhost` program to do this.
- In order to run Firefox on the Linux box, I have tell the Firefox process what X11 client I'm running it on. I can do this by setting the DISPLAY environment variable to something like "10.0.1.33:0.0". This means the X11 client is running the the machine on IP address 10.0.1.33, and I want you to use the first screen, and the first instance of the X11 client on that screen.
- Now, I can run Firefox on my Linux box, and the display will display on my Mac.

The problem you're running into is that there's simply no X11 client when you're starting FireFox as a daemon process. An X11 client is associated with a user and a display of some sort. The display could be a virtual display, but there's got to be an X11 client that's running and is addressable in some way, so the process knows where to display the output.

By the way, you said *daemon* which has a very, very specific meaning in Unix/Linux. A daemon is a process that runs in the background and usually has a service (and a port) associated with it. For example, there's an FTP daemon called `ftpd`, the mail server uses the sendmail daemon, ssh has the `sshd` daemon. Daemons have no display associated with them.

However, it looks like you might be using the word to mean launching Firefox via another process. Is that true? If so, you'll have to make sure that Firefox knows the X11 display to use (there's a command line setting to use to specify the display), and that your X11 client (your login session) has given permission for another process to update your display with the program window.

Can you please explain what you're trying to do in a bit more detail? If you simply want to download a file from a remote http server (which of course is running the http daemon process called `httpd`), you should use `curl` or `wget` which don't require a display and are way simpler to use. If you're trying to do something else, let us know exactly what it is.

Comment: Many thanks David W for your explanation. I am very new to Linux and have much to learn. Basically I am using a Lubuntu based box that runs apache2 server and my daemon auto runs at startup as a background process logging serial data to a sqlite database. The operator interface is via a firefox browser (via apache2 server) either remotely or locally on the box. Some options do not require firefox to run on the local box but if they do I want to start it from my daemon at boot up which reads its configuration from a squlite table. I will investigate on how to start X11 client from my daemon.

Comment: PS: I prefer to start firefox via my daemon because it has a number of configurations and functions that interfaces with the operator (via Ajax/php code running on my apache2 server). As far as I can tell I would class it as a daemon as it doesn't have a terminal interface but collects/logs data every second as well as provide a shared memory interface for php code running in apache2 server and is a crucial component of the whole system. Possibly I could launch firefox from another /etc/init.d/ script but then I would need to read my database file again as well?

Comment: Take a look at the various [VNC](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=vnc+client&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) clients for Unix/Linux. These clients create a virtual X11 Display. It might be possible to run these clients as a background process, and then be able to _peek_ at their display when you want to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox needs to know which display it should open on.  When you run it from within a gui, even through a terminal emulator, the `DISPLAY` environment variable is set to the appropriate value.  When you launch from the daemon, try `system("/usr/bin/firefox -display=:0")`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `DISPLAY` environment variable is properly set in your daemon to refer to the X server that you want your `firefox` to use.

If the daemon is run as a different user account than the user account that "owns" the X server that you want to use, you will also need to use `xauth(1)` to configure the authentication token to grant permission to use the X server.

Often times, it is far easier to use `ssh -X` to tunnel X *and* properly configure the `xauth(1)` tokens in one go than try to manage `xauth(1)` tokens yourself. Maybe adding `ssh -X` into your environment would be suitable, maybe not. (I've even used `ssh -X root@localhost` before when I needed to run an X client as `root` and didn't want to bother with configuring `xauth(1)` manually. `ssh(1)` is just so much easier.)

Comment: Thanks guys

Kevin when I try your suggestion I get the response "no display specified" ?

Comment: Using remote ssh access and setting DISPLAY=:0 I get "no display specified" error? 
David W -- My Daemon has a number of user control options, one of those is to be able to launch firebox browser after the daemon has started up. 
Typing env on the local machine gives DISPLAY=:0 also but if i try to do this system("/usr/bin/firefox -display=:0") from my C daemon doesn't work?